# How to view records made by a customer

Tags: php

Sorry for my ambiguous question on the last post on this. I am developing an eCommerce website for my assignment. What I want to achieve is that when a customer logs in to his account he should be able to see his account with all the items he purchased. I am using table orders for keeping all orders. I do not get any errors. I only get the table headings I created.

The query i am using is :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT orderID, cust_firstname, cust_lastname, 
cust_address, cust_phone, cust_country from orders  
where cust_firstname =" .$_SESSION['user_name']);
```

Please help

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem, what is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: ok and so when does the problem occur ? do you get a sql error ?

Comment: You should have post the error messages. And you forgot the '-signs, see also Vytautas's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT orderID,cust_firstname,cust_lastname,cust_address,cust_phone,cust_country from orders where cust_firstname ='" .$_SESSION['user_name']."'");
```

Comment: No I am not getting any error.

Comment: I added the query you gave me but it is not displaying anything still

Comment: your query is fine.. so your problem isn't here